# DIfference Between two dates in django queryset

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-rest-framework, django-queryset

models.py

```
class Operations(models.Model):
    model = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    process_status = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    created_date = models.DateField(null=True)
```

views.py

```
from django.db.models import DurationField, ExpressionWrapper, F
from datetime import date

today = date.today()
created_queryset=Operations.objects.filter(process_status__startswith='Created').values('model').aggregate(days_awaiting=ExpressionWrapper(F('created_date')-today.strftime("%Y-%m-%d"),output_field=DurationField())).order_by('-created_date')
```

I need output in no of days from today to the 'created_date' (Date format from Mysql database is in 2016-08-20)

Comment: Do you really use it for rest API? If yes, so do you use serialaizers?

Comment: I did not use any serializer @ТаалайДюшебеков , What i want is difference of date from database and today's date within django querset itself

Answer (score -1):

**This will work**

You can create two variables of your query type. then can find difference of these two variables.

variable 1: created_date

variable 2: today_date

difference=created_date - today_date

Comment: Thanks for your concern , But i need to differentiate in queryset